# pyinstaller .exe runs from command line, not double click in explorer

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

This has been asked several times before, but the answers don't seem to apply.

I create the exe with this command -

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_intel_thread.1.dll;.  unitTracker.py
```

If I run from the command line it works with no error msgs. If I double click in the File Explorer, the cmd window pops ups, sits around a while, then disappears, never visibly showing an error msg.

I created a simple .bat file:

```
unitTracker.exe
pause
```

Now the cmd window stays open after the .exe has run, but it shows nothing.

I added some diagnostic print() to my program, which now starts with:

```
if (__name__ == '__main__'):
  print ('starting')
  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
  print ('app created')
  myapp = UnitTracker()
  myapp.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I don't even get the "Starting" output, which suggests the problem is occurring before my program is even loaded.

The problem remains if I remove `--onefile`

Edit:
I realized that the cmd window in which the program successfully runs is an Anaconda window, whereas double clicking the .bat file produces a default cmd shell. That's one difference. I further refined this to checking the Anaconda env. The program runs in the env that pyinstaller was run in. It does not run in the base Anaconda environment. Isn't pyinstaller supposed to create a standalone program/bundle that doesn't rely on the environment? I know that sometimes it doesn't bundle a .dll without additional prompting, but in that case you get an error that the .dll was not found. I'm getting nothing.

Edit 2:
After a lot of hunting around, I was able to narrow it to a single import, which then allowed me to find the missing module in the huge list of missing modules.

`missing module named 'lxml.etree' - imported by openpyxl.xml (delayed, optional), openpyxl.xml.functions (conditional), sphinxcontrib.devhelp (optional)`

I've attempted to fix this by adding a `--paths=` flag pointing to the location of the relevant modules but I can't seem to get the right path. Going to keep banging on it.

Edit 3:
Here's an MWE for the issue:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
if (__name__ == '__main__'):
  print ("Hello World")
```

The code will run in the Ananconda shell in which pyinstaller was run. Run from cmd shell and you get nothing.
The warn-test.txt file indicates a missing module lxml.tree, as above.

[This issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5431) on the pyinstaller github repo shows the same problem. The solution posted there uses

`--collect-submodules lxml`

I tried that, but I'm still getting a missing module.

Edit 4:

Although the program runs in the Anaconda env it was built in, it turns out the env does not include lxml. I installed it and the problem has finally gone away.

Comment: the problem is in your imports, since the imports run before your `__main__`

Comment: @AhmedAEK - shouldn't issues in the imports result in errors to stdout? I'm getting nothing.

Comment: @Llaves i didn't say it's an import error, i said it's a problem in the imports, one of them is most likely crashing your application, or whatever code is above `__main__`, which we don't see

Comment: @AhmedAEK - I see the distinction, and you're right. It's an import that's creating a missing module warning. See Edit 2.

Comment: the problem can be as simple as a file missing by pyinstaller, and it may be as big as one of your imports crashing when frozen, the best action is to hire a consultant and have him sign an NDA if you aren't going to share the code.

Comment: I didn't post code before because it wasn't remotely an MWE - the code was way too big for anyone to be willing to look at. But now that I've narrowed it down to a specific import and then to a specific missing file, I have edited the question with an MWE.